# Chrome's Console Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, console

has anyone ever seem an autocomplete solution in JS that works like Chrome's Console? (I think this is in version 17+)

I am trying to build something using jQuery, but I can't imagine how the autocomplete placeholder that stays below the active text follows the cursor.

All the autocomplete thing, the search, sort, etc... I've already done, I just need a way that the placeholder follows the cursor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why not to use a text box and to call function on any key press/key down. Then the function will read the text that is currently enter and check your data structure for possible end of the word.

You can sort the possible answer and to write the first one for example with other color. If the user press space or enter to color the whore world with black, and if it is press tab to switch with other possible answer...

Do you mean this?I can write some code to show you want  I mean if this is what you need?

Comment: No, I don't need code. The main problem is layout. It looks like Chrome's Console uses an input with placeholder, but this placeholder isn't erased until there are no more options from the autocomplete box. I've already tried with a input and a span below it, but the font rendering is a bit different =[